# Not able to get snmptrapd traphandler to fire

Tags: linux, networking, snmp

The client system is running Pop OS (Ubuntu 12.1.0) with snmpd v5.9.1 and I'm sending trap messages from both an Ubuntu server (9.3) w/ snmpd v5.8 and a machine running TrueNAS Scale, (latest build 22.12.2) and snmpd v5.9, but nothing I do seems to get the client to  respond, receive, or execute any traphandle for any trap messages. I've reversed the setup (client/host) and the Ubuntu machine responds as expected to messages from the Pop machine, so I feel confident about the configuration, but I'm at a loss why it doesn't work the other way around and I'd appreciate any ideas or insight on the matter.

#### Setup

- `$ sudo tcpdump -i eno1 udp port 162` to monitor traffic
- `$ watch -d -n 1 tail foo.log` to watch for traphandle actions
- `$ sudo snmptrapd -D all -Cdfn -m all -Lo udp:162 -c snmptrapd.conf`

  - not running under systemd for more control while debugging the problem.

#### Execute

- `$ snmptrap -d -v2c -m all -c public <client_ip> 'foo' netSnmpExampleHeartbeatNotification netsnmpExampleHeartbeatRate i 123456`

#### Notes

- iptables are cleared/accept all, no other (known) firewalls.
- I've run `sudo python -m http.server 162` jic but it works.
- yes, `foo.sh` is executable

#### Configuration files

`/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`  # I thought `snmpd` wasn't needed for the trap daemon?

```
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>
sysServices    72
master  agentx
agentAddress 127.0.0.1,[::1]
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
rocommunity  public default -V systemonly
rocommunity6 public default -V systemonly
rouser authPrivUser authpriv -V systemonly
```

`~/snmptrapd.conf`

```
authCommunity log,execute,net public
traphandle default /home/me/foo.sh
```

`~/foo.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'trapped!' >> foo.log
```